# Remove/Delete/Empty precious insertBefore

Tags: jquery

I have a small function that's called when a link is clicked, and a new div i created before that layer. But how do i delete it next time a div is created in a new place? Right now it's just duplicating for each click.

Big thanks!

```
function Appe(source) {

$('<div id="image"></div>').insertBefore(source);

};
```

Comment: not clear .. provide html or make a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Each time this function is called it creates a new div called "image".. how do I remove each div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add remove div line

```
function Appe(source) {
  $('#image').remove();
  $('<div id="image"></div>').insertBefore(source);
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29L789pu/)